# How to set Cache-Headers via Middleware before Mvc and not be overriden by ResponseCacheAttribute?

Tags: caching, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.2 (preview3) project with several controllers decorated with `ResponseCacheAttribute` like this one:
`[ResponseCache(Location = ResponseCacheLocation.Any, Duration = 60)]`

Now I want to add a Middleware which is supposed to run before MVC and before Caching which might determine to not allow any clientside/proxy caching for this response.

But if I set `context.Response.Headers[HeaderNames.CacheControl] = "no-cache, no-store";` in the Middleware it gets overwritten by the `ResponseCacheAttribute` of the controllers later in the pipeline.

So my pipeline looks like this:

- Use new Middleware: checks for cachability, sets `no-store` under specific conditions
- UseResponseCaching
- UseMvc

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Have you tried writing the header after the call to `await next()` in your middleware?

Comment: Thanks. I tried that. But Response has started and can't be modified at this state according to the Docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/), it throws an exception.

Comment: Right, hmm.. There might be some *feature* in the HttpContext's Features collection that allows you to disable the MVC caching feature.. Not sure though

Comment: Yes, there is the `IResponseCachingFeature`, but then I have to register my middleware after ResponseCaching, otherwise it's not present. 
And I can't find any API to remove a feature...

Comment: [HttpResponse.OnStarting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpresponse.onstarting?view=aspnetcore-2.1) ?

Comment: Thanks. That's a possible API and let's me change the `Cache-Control` Header.